# AngularJS - how to override directive ngClick

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-click

I want to override directive ng-click: to some make some $rootscope changes before each execution of ng-click. How to do it?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can't override AngularJS built-in directives. However, you can define multiple directives with the same name and have them executed against the same element. By assigning appropriate `priority` to your directive, you can then control whether your directive runs before or after a built-in directive.

This [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/GhWmENlz908FTS1tnA0Q?p=preview) shows how to build an `ng-click` directive that executes before the built-in `ng-click` does. The code is also shown below.  When clicking the link, the custom `ng-click` will run first, then the built-in `ng-click` does.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

  <head>
    <script data-require="jquery@1.9.0" data-semver="1.9.0" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.0.7" data-semver="1.0.7" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <a ng-click="alert()">Click me</a>
  </body>

</html>
```

**script.js**

```
angular.module('app', [])
  .directive('ngClick', function($rootScope) {
      return {
        restrict: 'A',
        priority: 100, // give it higher priority than built-in ng-click
        link: function(scope, element, attr) {
          element.bind('click', function() {
            // do something with $rootScope here, as your question asks for that
            alert('overridden');
          })
        }
      }
  })
  .controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.alert = function() {
      alert('built-in!')
    }
  })
```

Comment: Buu, can we stop first ng-click totally? i mean after running 'overridden' alert, 'built-in' not to run.

Comment: Don't pass an expression to ng-click, see http://plnkr.co/edit/uROkIcGKLspLnVsjmAKn?p=preview. If you have to pass s/t, then don't handle it, e.g. $scope.alert = function() {}.

Comment: this is not the correct answer, checkout the Eric Chen one below!

Comment: Concur with JackNova, this answer is not correct.

* you CAN override/replace all directives as @eric-chen shows below
* this example approach will run into issues - you cannot have multiple directives on the same element requesting an isolate scope or setting a template. Eric's approach solves that too

Answer (score 80):

Every directive is a special service inside AngularJS, you can override or modify any service in AngularJS, including directive

For example remove built-in `ngClick`

```
angular.module('yourmodule',[]).config(function($provide){
    $provide.decorator('ngClickDirective', ['$delegate', function($delegate) {
        //$delegate is array of all ng-click directive
        //in this case first one is angular buildin ng-click
        //so we remove it.
        $delegate.shift();
        return $delegate;
    }]);
});
```

angular support multiple directives to the same name so you can register you own `ngClick` Directive

```
angular.module('yourmodule',[]).directive('ngClick',function (){
  return {
    restrict : 'A',
    replace : false,
    link : function(scope,el,attrs){
      el.bind('click',function(e){
        alert('do you feeling lucky');
      });
    }
  }
});
```

check out http://plnkr.co/edit/U2nlcA?p=preview
I wrote a sample that removed angular built-in `ng-click` and add a customized `ngClick`

Comment: How would you keep both delegates but let the first handler conditionally propagate to the built-in delegate?

Comment: @AlexWhite my guess is that it's impossible since the `click` binding is being done with `element.bind` inside another function callback already: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngEventDirs.js#L62

Comment: @AlexWhite the simple solution is to simulate this behavior by making a copy of the ngClick event handler and $parse usage in your directive and calling it conditionally from your event handler.