# How can I add a click and double click control to a row with AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

If I have AngularJS HTML that creates a *table* like this:

```
<tbody>
   <tr data-ng-repeat="row in grid.data">
      <td>{{ row.id }}</td>
      <td>{{ row.text }}</td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

How could I add in functionality so that one click on a row makes just that row highlighted and two clicks calls a function with the `row.id`?  Is there an `AngularJS` way to do this or would I have to use `jQuery`? I suspect the only way to do this is with `jQuery` but feel I should ask as an `AngularJS` question first.

Thanks

Comment: You can use [ngClick](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngClick) and [ngDblclick](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngDblclick). Can you provide a plunker or jsfiddle?

Comment: Would I need to put that on each cell or could I put it on the row?

Comment: I just realized. With one click I want to just make the one row I click on highlighted and remove any previous highlight. I think that might be more difficult to achieve.

Answer (score 4):

I found below from Jquery's website:

**"**
It is inadvisable to bind handlers to both the click and dblclick events for the same element. The sequence of events triggered varies from browser to browser, with some receiving two click events before the dblclick and others only one. 
**"**

It's better you can find another way to implement it, such as using the mouse hover and click event togather but not click and double click togather.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to go would probably be to go there first:

[Handling ng-click and ng-dblclick on the same element with AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20444409/handling-ng-click-and-ng-dblclick-on-the-same-element-with-angularjs)

in order to deal with the single and double click issue.
look here: http://plnkr.co/edit/on260PrRZ5mZqHOK6NXW?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

Angular itself has a built-in `[ng-click][1]` directive.

I would consider using this. However, you will have to build the double-click feature by yourself, i guess.

This should pe pretty simple and could be combined with the ng-click fired function. Just wait x seconds to determine whether or not the user has done 2 clicks.

Edit: Mea culpa, i had no idea about ngdblclick

Comment: How could I make it so only the row I click on is highlighted and all other rows lose highlight. Do you think this could be done with Angular?

Comment: Of course. I would begin with creating a directive that fits your needs. This directive could, for example, share scope with all instances and you could add and remove some css class attributes on click. There are a lot of ways to accomplish this, though. If you are unfamiliar with directives, i strongly recommend some lecture on the topic :)

Answer (score 0):

i think this works

html

```
       <tr ng-repeat="x in Humans" ng-dblclick="ReadId(x.Id)" >
            <td>{{x.Id}}</td>
            <td>{{x.Name}}</td>
            <td>{{x.Family}}</td>
            <td>{{x.Age}}</td>
        </tr>
```

javascript angular

```
        var z;
        $scope.ReadId = function (d) {
            z = d;
        }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).