# How can I get the click count

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

In an anchor tag I would like call one of two different events based on if the user clicked once or twice. However if I implement `ng-click` and `ng-dblclick`, both are activated.

Is there any way to route to the appropriate listener based on click count?

Comment: See https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/nA1i2raCcA0 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20444409/handling-ng-click-and-ng-dblclick-on-the-same-element-with-angularjs

Comment: Do you want to watch for a double mouse click (like on a desktop, two clicks within x amount of time) or just two clicks of the button.

Comment: I want to watch for a double click

Comment: thanks helpYou, looks like the right answer, but boy is that ugly!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a combination of ng-click and $timeout to count the number of times the function has been executed. the code could look like something like this;

```
 <a ng-click="clicked()" />


 $scope.clickCount = 0;
 var timeoutHandler = null;
 $scope.clicked = function()
 {
     if (timeoutHandler != null)
          $timeout.cancel( timeoutHandler );
     $scope.clickCount++;

     timeoutHandler = $timeout(function()
     {
         //now you know the number of clicks.
         //set the click count to zero for future clicks
         $scope.clickCount = 0;
     }, 500)
 }
```

Comment: I can't believe they didn't build something in for this!