# Understanding the working of ngClick and ngDblclick

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive, angularjs-ng-click

I was trying to figure out how `ngClick` and `ngDblclick` work in `angularjs`. The problem is that even while clicking twice, instead of calling `doubleclick` function once. Angular calls click function twice and double click function once.

HTML:

```
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
     <div class="button" ng-click="click()" ng-dblclick="dblclick()">
        Click
     </div>
     <div class="button" ng-click="reset()">
        Reset
     </div>
     <div>
        clicked:{{clicked}}
     </div>
     <div>
        double clicked : {{dblclicked}}
     </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
function MyCtrl($scope) {
   $scope.clicked = 0;
   $scope.dblclicked = 0;
   $scope.click = function(){
      $scope.clicked++;
   };
   $scope.dblclick = function(){
      $scope.dblclicked++;
   };
   $scope.reset = function(){
      $scope.clicked = 0;
      $scope.dblclicked = 0;
   };
}
```

JsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/9048/)

But this is not the case in `jQuery` wherein `$(someElement).click()` and `$(someElement).dblclick()` work as expected, which seems to be the ideal way to do it.

I have a fair idea that this is happening because they are implemented as directive in angular. Wherein in jQuery it works by listeners.

I see that you can eliminate this by using `$evalAsync`, but what reckons me is  why we need such an extra burden to achieve something which is very obvious.

Can someone tell me how to handle the scenario. Thanks in advance.

Comment: intresting... could this help https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/9826 ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Handling ng-click and ng-dblclick on the same element with AngularJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20444409/handling-ng-click-and-ng-dblclick-on-the-same-element-with-angularjs)

Comment: @OvidiuDolha the links which you suggested was something quite opposite to what i want to achieve. Shouldn't the click be prevented when i am trying to Double click.

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/4322 - it's been discussed by angular team