# how to override angularjs directive ngInclude

Tags: angularjs

How to override directive? I want on detective call do some my action(resolve url for ex.) then give control to regular directive.

`myApp.directive('ngInclude',
    [function ()    {
               // resolve url
    }]);`

Update:

Here is example based on answer below:
http://plnkr.co/edit/HZmyAW64xKhBsVCBkj8U?p=preview
but I don't know how change detective value.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [AngularJS - how to override directive ngClick](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18421732/angularjs-how-to-override-directive-ngclick)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is done by giving your directive a higher priority, like so:

```
 angular.module('myApp', [])
  .directive('ngInclude', function() {
      return {
        priority: 100,
        link: function(scope, element, attr) {
          //Logic goes here
          })
       }
    }
})
```

Comment: Could you provide example of changing Include URL?

Comment: That seems like a new question to me, the question asked here is how to override a directive. not how to write one.