# triggerHandler causing Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $apply already in progress error - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, onclick, jquery-triggerhandler

I am trying to trigger the click of a button when a key is pressed. I'm doing this using the `triggerHandler` function, but this is causing the error above. I'm thinking I must have created some kind of circular reference/loop, but I can't see where.

This is my HTML:

```
<button id="demoBtn1" hot-key-button hot-key="hotKeys.primaryTest" class="po-btn primary-btn" type="submit" ng-click="btnFunction()"></button>
```

Here's my controller:

```
.controller('BtnCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.checkKeyPress = function ($event, hotKeyObj) {
        for(var key in hotKeyObj) {
            if($event.keyCode == hotKeyObj[key].keyCode) {
                var id = hotKeyObj[key].btnId;
                hotKeyObj[key].funcTriggered(id);
            }
        }
    }
    $scope.clickFunction = function(id) {
        var currentButton = angular.element(document.getElementById(id));
        currentButton.triggerHandler("click");
    }
    $scope.btnFunction = function() {
        console.log("clickFunction1 has been triggered");
    }

    $scope.hotKeys = {
        'primaryTest': {
            keyCode: 49,
            keyShortcut: "1",
            label: "Button",
            btnId: 'demoBtn1',
            funcTriggered: $scope.clickFunction
        },
        // more objects here
        }
    }
})
```

And my directive is here:

```
.directive("hotKeyButton", function() {
    return {
        controller: 'BtnCtrl',
        scope: {
            hotKey: '='
        },
        transclude: true,
        template: "<div class='key-shortcut'>{{hotKey.keyShortcut}}</div><div class='hotkey-label'>{{hotKey.label}}</div>"
    };
})
```

It's a bit of a work in progress, so I suspect there might be small errors in places, but I'm primarily interested in the logic running from the keypress to `btnFunction` being triggered. The error fires on the `currentButton.triggerHandler("click")` line.

Can anyone see what I've done? Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since you have a problem with `$apply` in progress - you can just wrap your `triggerHandler` call into `$timeout` wrapper - just to make everything you need in another `$digest`-cycle, like this:

```
$scope.clickFunction = function(id) {
    var currentButton = angular.element(document.getElementById(id));
    $timeout(function () {
      currentButton.triggerHandler("click");
    });
}
```

After this everything will work OK.

- Also don't forget to `$inject` `$timeout` service into your `BtnCtrl`.
- Also i'm not sure you need to define `controller` property for your directive, but it's not a main case.

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/vO8MKAQ4397uqqcAFN1D?p=preview