# Count ng-if true statements in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ng-if, angularjs-ng-if

I have a page which shows different data with ng-ifs, I need to show how many of them are true on the same page. Just the number. The HTML is complex, but I have made a simpler version to understand how things work. Here is what the HTML looks like, and the data is being manipulated on the page as well, so the ng-if value can change after it has been rendered and hence the count on the page should be changing with it.

```
<div ng-if="abc">
  some data 1 
</div>
<div ng-if="!abc">
  some data 2
</div>
<div ng-if="xyz">
  some data 3
</div>
<div ng-if="abc">
  some data 4
</div>
<div ng-if="!xyz">
  some data 5
</div>
```

I made a plnkr as well.
http://plnkr.co/edit/5wdiSLhbHpOPJGjRn47L?p=preview

Thank you.

Comment: write a JS function to count it?

Comment: i think you can use an array instead of variables .. so that you can easily get the count

Comment: You could add a new ngIf directive. For details see http://stackoverflow.com/a/18425418/3892935

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pure JavaScript solution could be to add a class (or an attribute) to the HTML elements which have `ng-if` conditions, and then use `document.getElementsByClassName('class-name').length` to get the number of elements which have the `ng-if` condition true.

**Example:**

```
<div class="sample-class" ng-if="abc">
  some data 1 
</div>
<div class="sample-class" ng-if="!abc">
  some data 2
</div>
<div class="sample-class" ng-if="xyz">
  some data 3
</div>
<div class="sample-class" ng-if="abc">
  some data 4
</div>
<div class="sample-class" ng-if="!xyz">
  some data 5
</div>

<div>Total count is: {{getCount(); totalCount}}</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    angular.module('app', [])
    .controller('ctrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
        $scope.totalCount = 0;
        $scope.getCount = function(){
            $timeout(function(){
                $scope.totalCount = document.getElementsByClassName('sample-class').length;
            });
        };  
    }); 
</script>
```